# display xml file in browser with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, sitemap

This may be simple, although i'm having some trouble finding a solution.

i create a sitemap for my website in an xml file.i display content of xml file in aspx file.
but i want display xmlfile not in aspx.
when i use response.redirect("sitemap.xml"),it shows tree but i want to show only all content in sequential not in tree.

like this:
content of xmlfile:

```
<t><t1 p="s1"></t1><t2 p="s2"></t2></t>
```

but i want address bar=sitemap.xml and show like this:

p=s1p=s2 .....

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers will respect XSL declarations at the top of xml files.  If you have such a declaration at the top of your xml file like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="YourTransform.xsl"?>
```

It will apply the transform specified allowing you to output the xml however you want.  However, support is not universal.